# Pine Script EMA for one bar

Tags: pine-script-v5

I would like to calculate the EMA-13 for the bar from 21 days ago, how do I code this so I can use it after?

Thanks a lot

I would like to use this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use :

```
ta.ema(close[21], 13)
```